# How to retrieve friends via Facebook API 2.6?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve the ID's of all the user's friends.

What permissions do I need and how do I do that? (using either JS or PHP)

I want to eventually create something like this:
http://feedsguru.com/onesecret

Comment: please don´t try to create more of those spam apps...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible to retrieve friends just anyhow anymore, they removed that. You **can** retrieve a list of friends, but, only those that have given permissions to your app.

Here is the specification: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/

The only way to circumvent this would be to look through the users photos and get the people tagged in their pictures.

Comment: Thanks, looking through users photos seems like a nice solution for now!

Comment: don´t try to circumvent api limitations with those kind of workarounds...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the way to do it. I was also exploring this part.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/friends

Comment: friendlist only gets you the lists, not the friends. and /me/friends only gets you friends who authorized your app too.